# AsyncIO operation not writing to output directory in Apache Flink

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm very new to Flink, and trying out the Async IO operation by following the doc from [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html). I've a text file containing bunch of integers. I'm creating a stream on the file, then for each line, I'm making an async http request and finally storing the results into an output file. I created a fastAPI rest endpoint for managing simple get request. In the Flink code, I'm using the java [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) library to wrap the http call into an async request. But the problem is, when I run the Flink code, it always times out.

My input file looks something like:

```
-9
42
2
12
15
18
13
9
45  
-15
11
...
```

The fastAPI code goes something like this:

```
import time
from random import random
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/temperatures/{temperature}")
async def read_temperature(temperature: int):
    time.sleep(random())

    if temperature <= 0:
        return {"category": "insanely cold"}
    elif temperature <= 15:
        return {"category": "cold"}
    elif temperature <= 25:
        return {"category": "moderate"}
    elif temperature <= 35:
        return {"category": "moderately hot"}
    elif temperature <= 45:
        return {"category": "hot"}
    else:
        return {"category": "insanely hot"}
```

And finally, this is my Flink code:

```
import ...

public class AsyncHttpRequest extends RichAsyncFunction<String, Tuple2<String, String>> {
  private transient AsyncHttpClient client;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration parameters) {
    client = asyncHttpClient();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception {
    client.close();
  }
  
  @Override
  public void asyncInvoke(String key, final ResultFuture<Tuple2<String, String>> resultFuture) throws Exception {

    // issue the asynchronous request, receive a future for result
    String getURL = String.format("http://localhost:8000/temperatures/%s", key);
    final Future<Response> result = client.executeRequest(get(getURL).build());

    // set the callback to be executed once the request by the client is complete
    // the callback simply forwards the result to the result future
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      try {
        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(result.get().getResponseBody());
        return responseJson.getString("category");
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        return null;
      }
    }).thenAccept((String httpResult) -> {
      resultFuture.complete(Collections.singleton(new Tuple2<>(key, httpResult)));
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataStream<String> stream =
        env.readTextFile("file:///Users/me/http_input.txt");
    env.enableCheckpointing(10);

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> resultStream =
        AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait(
            stream, new AsyncHttpRequest(), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 10);

    final StreamingFileSink<Tuple2<String, String>> sink =
        StreamingFileSink.forRowFormat(
                new Path("file:///Users/me/http_output"),
                new SimpleStringEncoder<Tuple2<String, String>>("UTF-8"))
            .withRollingPolicy(
                DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
                    .withRolloverInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))                        .withInactivityInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
                    .withMaxPartSize(1024 * 1024)
                    .build())
            .build();

    resultStream.addSink(sink);
    env.execute("Async Http job");
  }
}
```

I get the following stacktrace when running the flink job:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(MiniClusterJobClient.java:117)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:237)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1046)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:573)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:447)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not complete the stream element: Record @ (undef) : 9.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.AsyncWaitOperator$ResultHandler.completeExceptionally(AsyncWaitOperator.java:383)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.async.AsyncFunction.timeout(AsyncFunction.java:97)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.AsyncWaitOperator.lambda$processElement$0(AsyncWaitOperator.java:197)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1318)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$null$17(StreamTask.java:1309)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxExecutorImpl.yield(MailboxExecutorImpl.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.AsyncWaitOperator.waitInFlightInputsFinished(AsyncWaitOperator.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.AsyncWaitOperator.endInput(AsyncWaitOperator.java:254)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.endOperatorInput(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.lambda$close$0(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.close(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.close(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.closeOperators(OperatorChain.java:439)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.afterInvoke(StreamTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:589)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:755)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:570)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Async function call has timed out.
    ... 20 more
```

Prining the Interruption/Execution Exception shows the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: executor not accepting a task
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:201)
    at com.merlot.data.pipeline.jobs.async.AsyncHttpRequest.lambda$asyncInvoke$0(AsyncHttpRequest.java:53)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: executor not accepting a task
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:179)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyChannelConnector$1.onFailure(NettyChannelConnector.java:108)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:28)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleChannelFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleChannelFutureListener.java:20)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:109)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.setFailure(DefaultChannelPromise.java:89)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:197)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:989)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:504)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:417)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:474)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task
    at io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup.getResolver(AddressResolverGroup.java:61)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:194)
    ... 21 more
```

I'm not really sure why the async function is timing out, because I can see the fastAPI endpoint is being queried in the console. Also, the endpoint is working fine, as all my postman requests go through perfectly fine. Any help in resolving the core issue is greatly appreciated.

I'm on MacOS Big Sur and using the following 3rd party libs:

```
implementation 'org.json:json:20201115'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'
implementation 'org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:2.12.2'
implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-core:1.12.2'
implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.12:1.12.2'
implementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.12:1.12.2'
```

**Update 1**: If I reduce the capacity to 1 (from 1000), then I don't get any error, but still the output is empty.

**Update 2**: After the suggestion made by @DavidAnderson I've enabled checkpointing. Now, I'm not seeing the timeout error, and my job is not getting terminated abruptly, which is a good news. But now, the output folder is still empty. I've updated my Flink code to reflect the checkpointing changes.

Comment: Are You getting any output at all ?

Comment: no, unfortunately.

Comment: Sure, do You have the rest of the logs that show what caused Async function call timeout ? If not you can try to override `timeout()` of Async function and print stacktrace from there. Generally, I'd say that first thing to verify would be to test with smaller sample like 5-10 elements. I am not sure how big Your file size is, but with the current settings You are basically sending 1000 records at once, which may be the reason for timeout You are getting.

Comment: Hi, this is the only output I get. My text file is pretty small, it has only 100 records. Even if I reduce the capacity to 10, it still gives the same error. I'll try overriding the timeout() and see what I get.

Comment: @DominikWosiński Updated the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you running this with checkpointing enabled? The StreamingFileSink only finalizes its output during checkpointing; checkpointing is required.

Comment: @DavidAnderson updated my question with checkpointing enabled, thank you.

Comment: Checkpointing every 10 milliseconds is unreasonably quick. Try changing that to 10 seconds, for example.

Comment: What version of Flink is this? Various versions of flink have different restrictions about how async i/o can be chained with other operators. I'm not sure if these restrictions are enforced by Flink itself, or if you have to manually work around the issues. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16219, for example. Depending on what your job graph actually looks like, you might need to manually break the chain between the readTextFile and the unorderedwait.

Answer (score 0):

A common issue with AsyncIO is that every concurrent request limit used in the execution stack should be sized appropriately. Some of these limits are implicit, e.g. if you don't supply your own thread pool to `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`, then it uses the shared `commonPool`, which is limited to a very small size, see https://dzone.com/articles/be-aware-of-forkjoinpoolcommonpool.

IIRC I use `AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait(capacity)` <= `HTTP client capacity` <= `executor capacity`. And the HTTP client capacity is often a limit of both its connection pool size and the number of connections per host.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, even if I use capacity as 1, I'm getting an empty output directory, with no files in it. So, I think maybe something else is causing this.

Comment: Just to help remove another possible source of the problem, what output (if any) do you get if you use `PrintSinkFunction` instead of `StreamingFileSink`?

Comment: Hi, with `PrintSinkFunction` I'm able to see all the records in the result. I used this: `PrintSinkFunction fn = new PrintSinkFunction(); resultStream.addSink(fn);`

Comment: I feel it's nothing to do with the async operation. I just removed all the async logic and tried writing the input data-frame directly to output path, without any transformation. Same issue persists.

Comment: Well, if you get the expected output with the `PrintSinkFunction`, and you don't get output with the `StreamingFileSink`, then it seems likely it's an issue with the sink. What if you don't use a rolling policy?

Comment: Doesn't help. That's probably expected, since the max size, rollover and inactivity period in the default policy is pretty large, compared what I was using.